# globally access the variable in perl

Tags: perl, import, export, global-variables

I have many files. In one file ie (`Lib::Utils`) I have all generic functions. I need to assign values to two variables and define the same in `Lib::Utils`, and I need to export that to other files. I should not declare the variable in other files.

I tried like the below

#### In Lib::Utils

```
package Lib::Utils;

require Exporter;
@ISA = qw(Exporter);

our $FAIL = 0;
our $SUCCESS = 1;
```

#### In test.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Lib::Utils;

our ($FAIL, $SUCCESS);

print("$FAIL\n$SUCCESS\n");
```

But I want this to export from `Lib::Utils` to all other files.

Answer (score 6):

There's no point in using `Exporter` without populating `@EXPORT` or `@EXPORT_OK`.

In `Lib/Utils.pm` you need to add

```
our @EXPORT_OK = qw/ $FAIL $SUCCESS /;
```

and change `test.pl` like this

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Lib::Utils qw/ $FAIL $SUCCESS /;

print "$_\n" for $FAIL, $SUCCESS;
```

Comment: @ssr1012: Fixed. Thank you.

Comment: Error Fixed.Thank you guys